# where to find whatIsAPrimitive in squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Hey, friends, I am using squeak for developing and I found primitives is useful, every comment belong to primitives all mentioned

`See Object     documentation whatIsAPrimitive`

Any friend can help where to see the object document **whatIsAPrimitive**, thanks first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find this documentation as follows: open a class browser, search for the class **Object**, go to the class side, and look for the method **whatIsAPrimitive**.

Alternatively, you can select the word *whatIsAPrimitive* and hit Ctrl-m (or Apple-m on Mac) to search for a method with that name.

Comment: Or use, in Squeak 4.x, the search bar in the top menu bar, or open up a Method Finder.

Comment: Thanks :) The document is also contained in Object. This kind of organizing mode is cool!